# Smarty html_select_date with empty fields

Tags: php, smarty

I'm having a problem using smarty's html_select_date custom function. Here I'm using it to display a date-of-birth selection field on a profile edit page, and mostly it works fine, but my problem is when I'm trying to tell smarty to set one or more of the fields to an empty value. I have this:

```
{assign var="dateofbirth" value="`$errors['DOB']['year']`-`$errors['DOB']['month']`-`$errors['DOB']['day']`"}
{html_select_date prefix="birthday" time=$dateofbirth start_year="-75" field_order="DMY" reverse_years="true" all_extra="onChange='saneDates()'" year_empty="Year" month_empty="Month" day_empty="Day"}
```

The $errors array is populated in PHP - my aim here is to build a string which, like the doc says, can indicate empty fields by omitting the missing value, e.g. "2013-12-". That part is working, I've dumped the output and I'm setting exactly that, but smarty is setting the day field to "13" (i.e. today's date) rather than the empty value I'm expecting.

What am I missing?

Comment: What about `"00-$errors['DOB']['month']-$errors['DOB']['year']"`, is it show you current date too?

Comment: No, doing that built a string `"00-12-2013"` - which resulted in the 30th of November being produced (PHP's intended behaviour).

Comment: I'm going to have to work around this problem because I have a deadline to meet, but I'll still give the bounty out if someone can explain WHY smarty is behaving this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this with a string time value. Smarty is trying to make a valid timestamp (see **shared.make_timestamp.php** in plugins directory for more information). When I had a look at **function.html_select_date.php**, I noted that you have to pass the time attribute as an associative array. The array keys must be the prefix + Year/Month/Day. I've tested this with some dummy data (Smarty 3.1.15)

`{assign 'dateofbirth' ['birthdayYear' => $errors.DOB.year,'birthdayMonth' => $errors.DOB.month, 'birthdayDay' => 0]}`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Fair enough. I thought it'd be something silly I wasn't doing right.